# Web Parts and Web Services

Tags: web-services, visual-studio-2008, sharepoint

I am working with Visual Studio 2008 and SharePoint 2007. I have created a web part , a web user control that pulls data from a web service (binding a DropDownlist from web service) has been wrapped in my Web Part. When I deploy my web part it doesn't show me the data pulled from web service (Empty DropDownList). please advice how to use web parts that interacts with external web services.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code you are using?

Comment: Is this web service call to a service outside your network?

Answer (score 0):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/826994

 This should have everything you need.